# Adding search ability to tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, uisearchbar

Am trying to add search ability to my app I added `search bar` to `nav bar` *programmatically* using this code

```
func addSearch(){
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
    searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    searchBar.delegate = self
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
}
```

I added the function to an `IBAction` I added delegate `UISearchBarDelegate`
also I have the following `var food = [Food]()`, 
`var filteredProducts =[Food]()`

I have this delegate methods

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text != nil || searchBar.text ==  ""{
        inSearchMode = false
        view.endEditing(true)
        tableView.reloadData()

    }else{
        inSearchMode = true
        let lower = searchBar.text!.lowercaseString
        filteredProducts = food.filter({$0.store_name.rangeOfString(searchBar.text!) != nil})
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

and i have everything setup in my tableView delegates but when i search it doesnt work

Comment: If I give sample code can you use that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39092510/how-to-create-uisearch-controller-with-customcell/39247549#39247549

Comment: Thank you i will try that now

Comment: Am having issue my array is not of type NSString @user3182143

Comment: did you use my code?

Comment: Yes but am using a custom class

Comment: show your error

Comment: It is working now thank you

Comment: What problem did you face?

Comment: Try changing the condition `searchBar.text != nil` to `searchBar.text == nil`